# DateTime format using t-sql string functions in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, datetime, substring, getdate

Using t-sql string functions

```
substring(convert(varchar, getdate(), 120),6, 11)
```

this will return `mm-dd hh:mm`

But then how do I get datetime format `yy-mm-dd hh:mm` ?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: As an aside, [please don't ever use `varchar` without a length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 120)` returns:

```
          1
1234567890123456789
2013-08-08 01:43:49
```

So change:

```
substring(..., 6, 11)
```

To:

```
substring(..., 3, 14)
```

And you'll get:

```
13-08-08 01:43
```